# Trying to return jsx from an event handler onSubmit of the form

Tags: reactjs, forms, jsx, onsubmit

I am trying to get some jsx onSubmit of the form...where i have called an event handler initialState

i have the computation and it is also showing in the console while logging it but unable to return the jsx and show it on the screen

class RenderSub extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marks: [{mark: ''}]
    }
}   

initialState = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.target.reset();
    let totalCreditScored = 0;
    let totalCredits = 0;
    let credit = this.props.lists.credits[this.props.lists.sem];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.marks.length; i++) {
        let x = this.state.marks[i].mark / 10;
        if(Number.isInteger(x)) {
            x = x + 1;
        } else {
            x = Math.ceil(x);
        }
        totalCreditScored = totalCreditScored + (x * credit[i]);
        totalCredits = totalCredits + 10 * credit[i];
    }
    let gpa = ((totalCreditScored / totalCredits) * 10).toFixed(2);
    this.setState({marks: [{mark: ''}]});
    console.log(gpa);
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>Your gpa is: {gpa}</h3>
        </div>
    );
}

render() {

    if(this.props.lists.sem === '') {
        console.log("hello");
        return <div></div>;

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.initialState}>
                {this.renderedLists()}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Branch CSE Other
Operating System -
Computer Graphics and Multimedia Systems -
Compiler Design -
Software Engineering -
Computer Networks -
Operating System Lab -
Compiler Lab -
Networking Lab -
Professional Training - I -
Submit
Your gpa is: 6.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The action called by `onSubmit` should not return any JSX. Instead, it should update some properties in your component's `state` and then your JSX should re-render based on these changes in the `state`

Something like that:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marks: [{mark: ''}]
    }
}   

initialState = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // e.target.reset();
    let totalCreditScored = 0;
    let totalCredits = 0;
    let credit = this.props.lists.credits[this.props.lists.sem];
    for(let i = 0; i < this.state.marks.length; i++) {
        let x = this.state.marks[i].mark / 10;
        if(Number.isInteger(x)) {
            x = x + 1;
        } else {
            x = Math.ceil(x);
        }
        totalCreditScored = totalCreditScored + (x * credit[i]);
        totalCredits = totalCredits + 10 * credit[i];
    }
    let gpa = ((totalCreditScored / totalCredits) * 10).toFixed(2);
    this.setState({marks: [{mark: ''}], gpa});
    console.log(gpa);
}

render() {

    if(this.props.lists.sem === '') {
        console.log("hello");
        return <div></div>;

    }

    if(this.state.gpa) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>Your gpa is: {gpa}</h3>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.initialState}>
                {this.renderedLists()}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```